# handle results from sqlite and pass them to custom list adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, custom-adapter

i work with sqlite and i fetch results from two columns(name,icon). i want to pass them to a custom adapter so as to set the name as the text of a (TextView) and then the icon as his drawableLeft with **setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds**.

first of all my insert in db are like this

```
  "Fruit / Vegetables,R.drawable.ic_launcher",
   "Meat / Fisth,R.drawable.ic_launcher"
```

in my listActivity i have this code after openning the db etc..

```
 mShopCatCursor = mDbHelper.fetchShoppingCategories();
 startManagingCursor(mShopCatCursor);

  String[] names,icons;
while(mShopCatCursor.moveToNext()){
    for(int i=-1,l=mShopCatCursor.getColumnCount(); ++i<l;){
        names[i]= mShopCatCursor.getString(0);
        icons[i]= mShopCatCursor.getString(1);
    }
}

    //this was taken from a tut 
    String[] from = new String[]{AppSQLite.KEY_NAME,AppSQLite.KEY_ICON};

    TextViewWithDrawableListAdapter adap = 
        new TextViewWithDrawableListAdapter(this, from);
    setListAdapter(adap);
```

what i want is to pass the names and the icons so the custom adapter do the following

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_item, null);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.main_menu_list_item);
```

i want this!!
for each list item to take the correct values.

```
            textView.setText(names[0]); 
    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icons[0], 0, 0, 0);

    return v;
}
```

i know namew[0] and icon are incorrect but i really cant find the way, even by searching the web for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt of all i don't get clear about what you want. If you want to pass the names and icons array to you custom adapter class then you can use constructor in your custom adapter class to receive them. Or read [this tutorial](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) .